# Use advanced xml on android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-activity

i have a xml file like:

```
<xml>
    <userlist sub='A'>
        <user id='1'>Daan</user>
        <user id='2'>Maarten</user>
        <user id='3'>Wannes</user>
        <user id='4'>Kobe</user>
        ...
    </userlist>
    <userlist sub='B'>
        <user id='5'>Fien</user>
        <user id='6'>Lisa</user>
        <user id='7'>Charlot</user>
        <user id='8'>Agnes</user>
        ...
    </userlist>
    <userdata>
        <userd id='1'>
            <phone>0123498519</phone>
            <genre>M</genre>
            ...
        </userd>
        <userd id='2'>
            <phone>0123958519</phone>
            <genre>M</genre>
            ...
        </userd>
        <userd id='3'>
            <phone>0143488569</phone>
            <genre>M</genre>
            ...
        </userd>
        ...
    </userdata>
</xml>
```

Now I use this code to get my list of users

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 
Document XmlCode = documentBuilder.parse(database);
XmlCode.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = XmlCode.getElementsByTagName("userlist");
```

But now I get all the `<user>` elements, how can I select only  the `<userlist>` where sub is 'A'?

And how can I select for example the phone number of of the user with id '3'?

Answer (score 0):

You parse the xml and build it into a data structure suitable for your application, which may be an in memory data structure or may be a SQLite DB that you then query.  You would never do those kind of operations on raw xml in any language or any platform-  its hideously inefficient.

Comment: Ok, i will do this but how can i get my data into the app?

I have found a way to work with it:
http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/ but not how i can get it into the app.